# In ZF, is there a total order on the set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$?

Tags: set-theory

In ZF, is there a total order on the set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$?

I was searching online for the answer but only found out that the set of all the rational functions is totally ordered.

Comment: Every set has a total order. In fact, every maximal (with respect to inclusion) order is total, and maximal orders exist because of Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified axiomatic system I'm interested in. Does the set of all the real functions has a total order in ZF?

Comment: What do you mean by "real functions"?

Comment: All the functions with real number inputs and outputs that have a domain over all the real number line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't there a total order of $\cal P(\Bbb R)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544551/why-isnt-there-a-total-order-of-cal-p-bbb-r) (notice that if $\lvert X\rvert\ge2$, then using indicator functions $\mathcal P(X)$ can be seen as a subset of $X^X$).

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223842/is-the-set-s-of-functions-s-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-from-the-rea?rq=1)